# Can I change the value of a static class member variable using a pointer in C++?

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I'm trying to change the value of a static class member variable by returning a pointer to main via an in-class function - the script isn't working and I've tried a few different things, so I decided to reach out for some help. Any ideas, or more efficient ways to do what I'm trying to do?

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class container
{
public:
    int accstatint()
    {
        int *ptr=&container::statint;
        return *ptr;
    }
private:
    static int statint;
};
int container::statint=0;

int addone(int *n)
{
    return *n++;
}

int main()
{
    container obj;
    int *ptr=obj.accstatint();
    addone(*ptr);
    cout<<*ptr;
}
```

Comment: accstatint() is returning integer value, not a pointer to an integer.. Also, why would you use a member (non-static) function to return a static member?
It should read   int* accstatint() { return &statint; }

Comment: I'll check that out again, although I think I tried that - I probably just typed it in wrong. Thanks a lot for helping bruv

Comment: This code should give you compilation errors

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
int accstatint()
{
    int *ptr=&container::statint;
    return *ptr;
}
```

This is returning a copy of the `int`, which means you cannot modify it. You need to return a reference (or pointer) to the `int` instead:

```
int& getStatInt() const { return container::statint; }
```

If you truly want to use a pointer, you can with this (but there's no advantage and you should prefer to use a reference):

```
int* getStatIntP() { return &container::statint; }
```

Now you can update the integer:

```
int main()
{
    container c;
    std::cout << c.getStatInt() << "\n"; // 0
    auto& ref = c.getStatInt();
    ref += 2;
    std::cout << c.getStatInt() << "\n"; //2
}
```

But all this begs the question: why do you require an object of the class to modify this? Why isn't it just `public`? I mean anyone can modify it via your class anyway, so why not just allow direct access to the `int` to modify. And if you're doing that, what is the purpose of it in the first place? You might want to have a `static int` in your class to keep track of how many instances of the class are constructed, but you wouldn't allow outside access to it. I can't help you with this without knowing what you're trying to do, you need to think about what your class is and what it does.

Comment: The OP asked for a pointer, not a reference; although I expect the reference is a better solution, this is worth pointing out. Also, in the non-MCVE version, perhaps all the constructors are `private` or `protected`, and it is difficult to get an instance of the glass. Then it might make sense to allow modification only by those who actually have an instance. I'm not sure where that would be a good idea, but it could happen.

Answer (score 1):

While a simple wrapper function would work:

```
int& acc_staticint() { return staticint; }
```

You could create a getter and setter, or, since you’re effectively making the variable `public` anyway, you could just do that and then refer to `container::staticint`.